# How do I join two dataframes (pandas) with different indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a way to transform sequence/genotype data from a csv format to a genepop format.

I have two dataframes: `df1` is empty, `df1.index` (rows = samples) consists of almost the same as `df2.index`, except I inserted "POP" in several places (to specify the different populations). `df2` holds the data, with `Loci` as columns.

I want to insert the values from `df2` into `df1`, keeping empty rows where `df1.index = 'POP'`.

I tried `join`, `combine`, `combine_first` and `concat`, but they all seem to take the rows that exist in both df's.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df1.join(df2)` should default to a `left` join which only preserves the columns from df1.  Is that what you want?  In pandas 0.10 that is the default.

Comment: umm, not really. I'd like to preserve the indices of `df1`, the columns are fine.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want an 'outer' `join`:

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

Comment: thx Hayden. it keeps the rows, however, the 'POP' rows are being lumped together, that means I lose the order.